# Filter Woo Commerce widget categories based on search query

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have been trying to work this out for days now and getting nowhere..Basically what im trying to achieve is, when a person uses's the product search form, the product category widget only displays the relevant categories on the results page instead of showing them all.

[image]

Any help - directions would be appreciated.

Comment: In order to help you'll need to provide a bit more information about what you've tried that has not worked, and also what additional plugins you may have tried. What you're looking for doesn't sound like something that can be done with the base installation.

Comment: Hi Liam 
Im currently using relevanssi plugin to handle the search forms,

Comment: Hi Liam 
Im currently using relevanssi plugin to handle the search forms,so using the this 
https://www.relevanssi.com/knowledge-base/category-filter-search-results-pages/
i can get a the category working but wanted to hook it into the default woo product category filter .

Answer (score 0):

Does [product_categories number=""] display the correct parent, or "0" ?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bwoocommerce%5D+category - you should be able to find some assistance here.

Comment: I'm not using the shortcode - using the default products category widget, so hoping there was a hook or function which would hide the categories not relevant  to the search query /?s=hoodie&post_type=product